# How does dropbox monitoring?

Tags: synchronization, operating-system, filesystems, monitoring, dropbox

Which mechanism does [Dropbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropbox_%28service%29) use to monitor the folders? I am interested in the mechanism supported by a programming language, by operating systems or some file system functionalities.

Comment: Perfectly valid question if a bit rephrased. Don't know who and why marked it as offtopic.

Comment: On Windows the best way (and it's used by many tools) is to employ a filesystem filter driver - this is a reliable and precise mechanism unlike FindFirstChangeNotification and its derivatives (FileSystemWatcher etc). The only drawback is writing a driver yourself is time-consuming and complicated task. Use of the pre-created driver solves this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of options you may want to consider:

- Java has a [WatchService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/WatchService.html)
- .NET has a [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx)
- Flavors of Linux can use [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify)
- Windows native has [FindFirstChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- You can implement a custom file system using [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/)
- OP also pointed to Apache Commons IO's [solution](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/monitor/package-summary.html) for Java.

Some info used from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517460/is-there-anything-like-inotify-on-windows) SO question.

Comment: Thank you, that is a nice overview. I am currently testing some monitoring functionalities with Java, but I am worried about some [usability problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255463/java7-watchservice-access-denied-error-trying-to-delete-recursively-watched-ne).

Comment: That's the risk of using something like Java since it's basically going to wrap what the native OS provides.  But I think that's also a windows idiom - it's like having a text file open and then deleting the folder containing that file - usually windows complains.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it's just a simple file lock. What do you think about the [Apache Commons IO features for recursive file monitoring](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/monitor/package-summary.html)?

Comment: I had never seen that before, but it looks interesting.  Thanks for the info!  Will add to the answer.  I did a quick skim of the source - it seems that its basically a nice little wrapper around polling the file system for changes.

Comment: I just tested the API. The key benefit is that it doesn't need an open file handle all the time.

Comment: That's pretty cool - what interval did you use for your monitor (or what frequency were you calling checkAndNotify)?  I guess the con would be that you may not get instant changes, but a slight delay is probably acceptable

Comment: For test purposes I tried an interval of 250 ms. I have seen that the API implements a file tree walker which compares the old and new state and I don't know whether 250 ms are a to short interval.